# Route resolving + multiple controller combo?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to combine 2 concepts and I'm having trouble making them work together.

`Concept 1`: Route resolving. This is easy to explain, I just want to resolve certain models like this:

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/news", {
    templateUrl: "news.html",
    controller: "newsCtrl",
    resolve: { news: function(Model) { return Model.news.getList(); }
```

`Concept 1`: The idea of a 'base controller' that I can use in the route `controller: xyz`, then in the actual view html I load the 'sub' controller. For instance....

**app.js**

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/news/latest", {
    templateUrl: "news-latest.html",
    controller: "newsCtrl"
```

**news-latest.html**

```
<div ng-controller="newsLatestCtrl">
...
</div>
```

This will allow me to put my common code inside `newsCtrl`, and `/news/latest` specific code in `newsLatestCtrl`

The problem is I need to combine these two concepts, but it's hard to do that because I can't pass the local variables in to the 'sub' controller, only the main controller.

The only options I see don't really look like good ideas...

1. In the base controller, add the local variable as a `$scope` variable (seems dirty, especially for large controllers)
2. Move it into a service (it's not really relevant to any services though...)
3. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to help you when we don't know what the "base controller"'s responsibilities are. For me, the Concept 3 you are looking for is as follows:

```
$routeProvider
.when("/news", {
templateUrl: "news.html",
controller: "newsCtrl",
resolve: { news: function(Model) { return Model.news.getList(); })
.when("/news/latest", {
templateUrl: "news.html",
controller: "newsLatestCtrl"},
resolve: { newsLatest: function(Model) { return Model.news.getLatest(); });

module.controller('newsCtrl', function($scope, news) { 
    /* common code you want to share */ 
});

module.controller('newsLatestCtrl', function($scope, newsLatest, $controller) {
   // instantiate your "base controller"
   var ctrl = $controller('newsCtrl', {
       "$scope": $scope,
       "news": newsLatest
   });
   // customize and add special code for latest news
});
```

Comment: Oh snap... I didn't know you could do that. let me try that!