# Combining Nearly Identical Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

In my angular application, I have two tables, each with their own controllers.  These two tables use ng-repeat to present information retrived from a REST API.  The controllers for these two tables interact with the API in the same way, through the same service, simply providing a different path.
Most of my logic has been abstracted into services, but it still feels silly duplicating all the code that's left between the two controller's, changing only one value.  I am probably thinking about this the wrong way, but I can't seem to find a clean way to 'construct' a controller with parameters.

I have looked into using a directive with a 'path' attribute, but since the rows will be different, I would just end up with two separate directives/templates.  To avoid this, I tried transcluding the ng-repeat that builds the table rows, but it turns out that the transcluded elements are still tied to the outer scope, not that of the directive (and it's controller).

Is there a proper "angular" way to do this?

Comment: Hi are you using Angular 2 / Angular 1?

Comment: You can create an instance of one controller inside another with `$controller` service and adjust it to your needs. [See an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27850260/878514).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the *base* controller in another one and adjust its values as you need or prepare the scope prior to creating the controller.

```
angular.module('example')
.controller('BaseController', function($scope, MyService) {
  var receiveData = function(data) { /* ... */ };
  MyService.fetchData($scope.customUrl || '/default/url').then(receiveData);
  // the rest of the controller's code
});
.controller('AnotherController', function($scope, $controller) {
  $scope.customUrl = '/custom/url';
  var controller = $controller('BaseController', {$scope: $scope});
});
```

Another option is to read the values from the element that controller is associated with.

```js
angular.module('example', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope, $attrs) {
    var url = $attrs.url || '/default/url';
    $scope.url = url;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="example">
  <div ng-controller="MyController" url="/custom/url">
    The controller's URL is <code>{{ url }}</code>.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't realize you could access attributes so easily, that works perfectly! Thanks